# Is Vanco a supported payment processor?

Tags: drupal, payment-processor, vanco

Is there any CiviCRM support for Vanco as a payment processor? I do not see them on the list of payment processors in the current release. I searched the exchange and did not find them mentioned. I saw a two year-old posting on Drupal for a module, but the instructions seem out of date.

CiviHosting told me it works with the current release of CiviCRM and Drupal 7, but when asked how to do it, they tell me they do not know.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Vanco was a sponsor at CiviCon Denver last month - so I'm guessing there's support!  I don't have details though, or I'd post an answer.  Sorry I don't have more!

Answer (score 6):

We developed the Vanco payment processor several years back and it's working through version 4.4.  We are talking with Vanco about updating it; I'm fairly positive it will not work for 4.6.  We should have a plan next week.

Comment: is the 4.4 extension publically available? When i looked earlier today, i could only find the 4.2 version

Comment: Here's the [github link](https://github.com/backoffice/Vanco-processor/archive/VancoPaymentProcessor_4.4.x.zip)

Comment: Lobo we were not comfortable making it public because Vanco was not willing to provide support; now that Vanco has a new management team they are looking to grow their integration business.   We have asked them to resolve a few issues before we were willing to upgrade to their processor and they have made significant progress. Hopefully we'll be starting on the 4.5/4.6 upgrade in a couple weeks.  We'll make this a public extension.

Comment: This is good news. Due to the needs of a client we have downgraded our plan from 4.6 to 4.4 to continue their use of Vanco as payment processor. We have found both Vanco and Back Office Thinking helpful.

Comment: When I set vanco payment processor as the default (civicrm v.4.4) I get an error when I attempt to create a contribute page, due to a non-existent variable in the contribute-page table.  However, the field does exist in the contribute-recurring table. (payment_processor_id) So If I do not have vanco set as the default, and set up a contribute-page for recurring, it appears to work (at least no error messages).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Vanco is interested in ensuring there is support for the plugin integrating it and CiviCRM. Speaking as a Vanco employee, If I cannot help you, I will find someone here who can.

To prevent spam, you can find me on LinkedIn at j.c. grogan

Comment: Please do not make commercial solicitations. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/tour) for additional guidance, as StackExchange is not a discussion forum and the guidelines for answers are stricter.